# skipped trouble with getchar and scanf

Tags: c, ubuntu, scanf, getchar

I recently started to program in C and im having trouble with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PI 3.1416

int main () {
    float x;
    int y;

    x = PI;

    printf("Enter y: ");
    scanf(" %i", &y);
    printf("The new value of y is: %i.\n\n",y);

    x = x * y;
    printf("The new value of x is: %f.\n\n",x);


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

the problem appears with the `getchar()` at the end, the program shutdown and doesnt wait for the input. I have found a solution i dont like at all and is by adding 2 times `getchar()`. Is there any way around it?, im using ubuntu so `system("pause")` is not an option

Comment: the problem with the getchar() needing to be repeated is the first call gets the new line from the entering of y by the user.  BTW: the 'Enter y: ' does not tell the user to enter an integer, so the user could (never trust what a user enters) 'aaaaaa'. (or similar)  then the scanf() would fail.  This means the returned value from scanf should always be checked to ensure the operation was successful (in this case, the returned value should be 1).

Comment: 'x' is a float, so PI should be defined as '#define PI (3.1416f)  Note the 'f' on the end, indicating a float number.  Otherwise, this will be a double number and a conversion will have to be added, by the compiler, to convert from double to float.  The '(' and ')'  should always be used around #defined numbers, so text replacements, when the macros is invoked, do not result in unwanted/unexpected code sequences.

Comment: the user of this program, including yourself in the future, will have no knowledge of the significance of 'x' and 'y', so display useful text with the printf statements, so the user will be informed of what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scanf` command does not consume the Enter key that you pressed after entering `y`.  So the `getchar()` happily consumes it.

One solution is to consume the rest of the input line after reading `y`; the code for that looks like:

```
int ch; while ( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF ) {}
```

Although there are other options for pausing at the end of a program, this is probably a good idea anyway because it will be necessary if you later expand your program to expect string or character input.

Answer (score 1):

A good general solution to this problem is to read input from the user using `fgets`, and then scan it with `sscanf`:

```
char ln[1024];
printf("Enter y: ");
fgets(ln, 1024, stdin);
sscanf(ln, "%d", &y);
```

You will still need to check the return values of `fgets` and `sscanf` for error conditions, but it is easier to handle line-oriented input this way.